# Find the maximum amount of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the maximum amount of numbers from $1500$ to $2700$ (including $1500$ and $2700$) fitting in the criteria: the sum of any two of these numbers should not divide by 6?

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The only thing of interest here about the factorization of $6$ is that $6$ is even.

Comment: it means that only one number in the maximal set can be divisible by 6 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested in the remainders modulo $6$ of the numbers.
In the allowed range, there are $201$ multiples of $6$, and for all other remainders, there are $200$ numbers.

If we pick at least one number $\equiv 1\pmod 6$, we cannot pick any number $\equiv 5\pmod 6$ and vice versa. But we can definitely pick all numbers of the same remainder - which gives us $200$ numbers.
The same holds for $2\pmod 6$ vs. $4\pmod 6$, giving us $200$ numbers more.
Additionally, we can take *one* number $\equiv 0\pmod6$ and *one* number $\equiv 3\pmod 6$.
In total, that's $$402 $$numbers.